# "Those were among the few times" in "Hillbilly Elegy"

Tags: meaning, pronouns, antecedents

English is not my mother tongue. So many times I have problems understanding exact meaning of it.

While I was reading *Hillbilly Elegy*, I found a word quite confusing.

> I thought about losing my temper with Mom or Linsay, or Mamaw, and how **those** were among the few times Papaw ever showed a mean streak, because, as he once told me, "the measure of a man is how he treats the women in his family."

What does *those* mean?  Does it mean Mom, Linsay and Mamaw? Or grandpa losing his temper with them?

Answer (score 5):

The sentence is a bit loosely constructed.  "Those" is clearly plural, but it is referring back to a thing that was not indicated as plural or even really as an event: "losing my temper".

It might have been more clearly written as "I thought about the times I lost my temper with Mom or Linsay or Mamaw, and how those were among the few times ...".

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation !